# Powershell PostrgreSQL query returns only fieldcount instead of value

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I am trying to get the values of the first twenty rows of column called list_name from the table called mailing_list_membership.

```
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
$DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand();

$DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT list_name FROM mailing_list_membership LIMIT 20";
$list_name_rows_value  =  $DBCmd.ExecuteReader();

Write-output  $list_name_rows_value 
$DBConn.Close();
```

However, in powershell for the variable list_name_rows_value it only returns the field count.

```
FieldCount
----------
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
```

Comment: Try `$rdr = $DBCmd.ExecuteReader(); $tbl = New-Object System.Data.DataTable; $tbl.Load($rdr); $rdr.Close(); $tbl | ft -AutoSize`

Comment: Okay. That worked. What is it called that those commands do? Its taking that list and making it into an object and then formatting it.... Is there a general name for that so I can view a tutorial series on it....

Comment: It's called "filling a datatable" ;) PowerShell knows how to handle datatables. With `SqlDataReader` objects you need to do the work yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `SqlDataReader` objects you need to traverse the result set yourself, e.g. like this:

```
$rdr = $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($rdr.Read()) {
  $rdr.GetValue(0)
}
```

It's more convenient to have the reader fill a datatable that you can display using the regular `Format-*` cmdlets:

```
$rdr = $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
$tbl = New-Object Data.DataTable
$tbl.Load($rdr)
$rdr.Close()

$tbl | Format-Table -AutoSize
```